# Export security group from office 365

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, o365-flow

I try to export my security groups, and after import and delete more than 1 groups.

```
$test = Get-MsolGroup | Export-Csv -path c:\temp\list.csv -encoding UTF8
```

After import it:

```
$groups= Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\test.csv
```

But now the format is not good for foreach script:

```
foreach ($group in $groups) {
 $objectID = $group.ObjectID
 Remove-MsolGroup -ObjectId $objectID
}
```

Comment: Could you include the error you are getting with the above script??

Comment: Error text:
`Remove-AzureADGroup : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.
At line:3 char:32
+  Remove-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $objectID
+                                ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-AzureADGroup], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.Remov
   eGroup`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the AzureAD powershell commands vs the MSOL.  Eventually the AzureAD modules are going away but for now this should work.

```
Connect-AzureAD

$test = Get-AzureADGroup | Export-Csv -path C:\temp\list.csv -encoding UTF8

$groups= Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\test.csv

foreach ($group in $groups) {
 $objectID = $group.ObjectID
 Remove-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $objectID
}
```

Comment: Beetwen the export and import, i want to delete rows from list. When i try to save csv the format is modify. I think that format is cause my problem

Comment: Error text:
`Remove-AzureADGroup : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.
At line:3 char:32
+  Remove-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $objectID
+                                ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-AzureADGroup], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.Remov
   eGroup`

Comment: Before the foreach, write-host $groups to ensure you are reading in the input file properly.  It seems like you either have an empty or badly formatted test.cvs file (or the wrong path).